# Laravel10 Filament/ Excel export: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel-blade, export-to-excel, laravel-10, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm trying to install Excel Export in my Filament admin resources by running "composer require pxlrbt/filament-excel" and I'm getting this error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- pxlrbt/filament-excel[0.1.0, ..., 0.1.4, v1.0.0, ..., v1.1.13] require maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.55].
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.46, ..., 3.1.55] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.29.0].
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.29.0] require ext-zip * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's zip extension.
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.25] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.26, ..., 3.1.35] require illuminate/support 5.8.*|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.36, ..., 3.1.45] require illuminate/support 5.8.*|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.16] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- pxlrbt/filament-excel[v2.0.0, ..., v2.3.1] require filament/filament ^3.0.0-stable -> found filament/filament[v3.0.0, ..., v3.2.61] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.0).
- Root composer.json requires pxlrbt/filament-excel * -> satisfiable by pxlrbt/filament-excel[0.1.0, ..., 0.1.4, v1.0.0, ..., v1.1.13, v2.0.0, ..., v2.3.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-zip` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require pxlrbt/filament-excel:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require pxlrbt/filament-excel:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Any one to help fix this?

I tried running "composer require psr/simple-cache:^2.0 pxlrbt/filament-excel" and got the same error.